# How can I solve this tricky PHP function task?

Tags: php, arrays

This one is a little bit difficult to explain but I will do my best to make it clear.

How can I make it so I can insert all the elements of an array inside a loop into a new array after a function has finished being called multiple times?

For example, if this function gets called like multiple times inside a loop.  What should I do merge array1, array 2, array3 shown by the var_dump into one array after the function has finished being called so that new array $array_total has the elements of array1,array2 and array3 after using array_merge? An example would be appreciated!

```
<?php
function data($param1, $param2) {
    $new_array = array();
    echo $param1."-".$param2;
    foreach($products as $key => $value) {
        array_push($new_array,$value); // inserts all the values of array $products into new array $new_array everytime the function is called.
    }
    var_dump($new_array); // this will generate will display array(1), array(2) and array(3) if the function below has been called 3 times for example .
}

foreach($form as $form_id => $form_title) {
    data($form_id,$form_title);
}
?>
```

Comment: Give expected input and result  .. this would make your question more clear ...

Comment: I already mentioned it in my question .. after the function has finished being called let's say 3 times .. I would like the $new_array to contain all the values generated inserted by the loop inside the function from the all the 3 times the function was called

Comment: `$array_push` is probably wrong. Please provide a input and expected output.

Comment: You lost me at "after using array_merge"  If there is a function called array_merge, then what exactly do you want to do to the arrays after they're merged?

Comment: @Unipartisandev I want to use array_merge to put all the elements of the arrays create inside the loop of the function into a new array.

Comment: This function does not do anything, right? Your inner variables are not send from anywhere, and array_push should be function, not variable. However, it's not clear what you really want to achieve.

Comment: I asked you to provide information because your code is not clear ... typical example where did you get `$products` ???

Comment: It's just pseudo code man

Comment: If you write pseudo code, it at least should speak for itself. Leaving a variable unspecified in pseudo code what it exactly represents makes totally no sense. An example of such a useless variable is `$products` in your example. As it's not clear what you're trying to do, no good suggestion can be given.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You could store the inserted data in a global variable (instead of instantiating a new array every time the function is called). The code could look like this:

```
<?php
$global_array = array();

function data($param1, $param2){
    global $global_array;   // <-- reference the global variable '$global_array'
                            // (omitting this will create a new, empty, local variable)
    forEach ($products as $key => $value) {
        $global_array[] = $value;
    }
}

forEach ($form as $form_id => $form_title) {
    data($form_id, $form_title);
}
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://ideone.com/W1qKzH)**.

For more info about the scope of variables in PHP and the use of the keyword 'global', take a look at **[the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)**.

Comment: -1 as globals are _very_ rarely a good idea and this not a situation in which they are.

Comment: Thank you , you were of great help man ... I appreciate it !!!

Comment: plz do not use global vars like mentiones in my comment below

Answer (score 4):

Use a class and please no global variables:

```
class List {

 private $list = array();

 public function addList($listToAdd) {
  foreach($listToAdd as $element) {
   $this->list[] = $element;
  }
 }

 public function getList() {
  return $this->list;
 }

}

//TEST
$list = new List();
$list->add(array(2,3));
$list->add(array(6,5));

$listTogether = $list->getList();
var_dump($listTogether);
```

Comment: May I ask why I shouldn't use global variables ?

Comment: @user1787184 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable

Comment: Reasons: 
1) each variable has to have its own area of validity
2) you can redeclare a local variable with the same name so that the global is overwritten
3) you cannot make validation at setting at one point, because it can be set anywhere => you cannot be sure what is in that global variable
All the problems can lead to bug and lot of time fix it. So its better to not use it.